# How can I Return an array from a function without using malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, pointers, return

I've been struggling with a simple task in C... (It's been a while.) I need to build a function that creates and resets an array of structs without using any memory allocation functions.

I originally designed it with malloc:

```
typedef struct {
    int ..
    int ..
} Branch;

Branch* createBranchList (int N)
{
    Branch *List;
    Branch reSet = {0}; // a zero'd Branch struct used for the resetting process
    int i;

    if(!(List=(Branch*)malloc(sizeof(Branch)*N))){
        printf("Allocation error");
        return NULL;
    }

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        List[i] = reSet;

    return List;
}
```

Now how can I do this without using memory allocation? Can I return a reference? I don't think so.

Thanks anyone for helping out.

Comment: In c you can not return a reference because there is no such thing.

Answer (score 7):

**Safe method (1):**

Define a struct with an array member, then return that.

e.g.:

```
struct MyContainer {
    Thing x[42];
};

MyContainer foo(void) {
    MyContainer m;
    m.x[0] = 5;
    m.x[1] = 10;
    ...
    return m;
}
```

Obviously, this method will not be possible if the array size is not known to the function at compile-time.

**Safe method (2):**

Have the caller pass in the array as an argument.

e.g.:

```
foo(Thing *things, int N) {
    thing[0] = 5;
    thing[1] = 10;
    ...
}
```

**Unsafe method:**

Declare a static local array, and return a pointer to that.

This "works" because a static array is not deallocated when it goes out of scope.  But it's unsafe because the array will be overwritten next time you use the function (particularly bad in a multi-threaded scenario).

This method will also not be possible if the array size is not known to the function at compile-time.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I was leaving that as exercise for the reader, but fair enough!

Comment: Thank you, 1st - i cant use malloc cause thats the requierment of the excersize. 2nd- thank you ill probably use the first method and just pre set a fixed size array in the struct or main function.

Comment: Does method 1 hold the array on the stack, and pass just the pointer back?